# PySpark throws ImportError, but Module actually exists and works well

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, cloudera, apache-spark-sql, fuzzywuzzy

I am using Cloudera and the Spark version is 2.1.0.

I was trying to crossJoin two tables and create a column with fuzzy match ratio (thus I need to import `fuzzywuzzy`). Here is the code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
def fuzzy_ratio(x,y):
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    res = fuzz.token_set_ratio(x,y)
    return res

fuzz_udf = F.udf(fuzzy_ratio,IntegerType())  # register UDF

Master = tableA.crossJoin(tableB) \
               .withColumn('ratio',fuzz_udf(tableA['colA'],tableB['colB']))
```

And it throws

```
ImportError: No module named fuzzywuzzy

at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:796)
```

But `fuzzy.token_set_ratio` works when I input it in the interactive shell. So I really don't know what's going on here.

Could anybody please help with my question? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the package fuzzywuzzy is not available in all the worker nodes. One workaround is for you to install this package in all the worker nodes.

For standardizing this setup, it needs cluster level configuration. See [this](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-prepare-your-apache-hadoop-cluster-for-pyspark-jobs/) cloudera link for more details.

Comment: @JingyingZhou you are welcome - please accept the answer  :)

Comment: the link you provided is broken

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar error and I added the fuzzywuzzy dependency to my spark submit command.

First zip the two package folders.In my case, the folders are at location `C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy` and `C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy-0.15.0.dist-info`

I then added the zip file to `spark-submit` command as 
`../bin/spark-submit /path/to/mycode.py --py-files /path/to/fuzzywuzzy.zip`

This makes sure that all worker nodes get the fuzzywuzzy dependency.

There is also an option to add this dependency later in sparkContext  as `spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('/path/to/fuzzywuzzy.zip')`